What is the difference between GPT-4o-global-deployment and GPT-4o-Regional-API in Azure OpenAI?
I see in the Microsoft Pricing calculator:

What is the difference between GPT-4o-global-deployment and GPT-4o-Regional-API in Azure OpenAI?

Update (2024-10-03): the new (introduced around 2024-10-01) Azure UI explains the difference between GPT-4o-global-deployment and GPT-4o-Regional-API in Azure OpenAI:


Standard: Pay Per API call, with lower rate limits. Adheres to Azure data residency promises. Best for intermittent workloads with low to medium volume. Learn more about Standard deployment type  (screenshot)
Global (Standard): Pay per API call with higher rate limits. Traffic is routed globally and does not adhere to Azure data residency promises. Recommended starting point for most scenarios except those with data residency requirements. Learn more about Global deployment type  (screenshot)



Reddit user dwaynelovesbridge answered the following:

Global gets routed to whatever region happens to have capacity (including other countries that may be a compliance no no for your company). Regional stays within a given region, but with the caveat that capacity is reduced and costs are higher.

